# Dart: mapping a list (list.map)

Tags: functional-programming, dart, flutter

I have a list of `String`s, e.g.,

```
var moviesTitles = ['Inception', 'Heat', 'Spider Man'];
```

and wanted to use `moviesTitles.map` to convert them to a list of `Tab` `Widget`s in Flutter.

Answer (score 242, accepted):

you can use

`moviesTitles.map((title) => Tab(text: title)).toList()`

example:

```
    bottom: new TabBar(
      controller: _controller,
      isScrollable: true,
      tabs:
        moviesTitles.map((title) => Tab(text: title)).toList()
      ,
    ),
```

Comment: Why do we need `toList`?

Comment: @onmyway133 because the question is about mapping a list

Comment: @AbdulMomenعبدالمؤمن I believe the question is why is it needed in the first place.

In Swift, mapping an Array<E> returns an Array<R> of the new result type. Why is the result of mapping a Dart List<E> not already a list?

Comment: @MichaelLong becaues here, in Dart, `map<T>` returns an `Iterable<T>` instead of a `List<T>`

Comment: The `Iterable` that `map()` returns is lazy. It isn't evaluated yet, only when somebody actually iterates it. Calling `toList()`, in addition to returning an actual list, forces this evaluation.

Comment: How can we use map on list object type array? final List filterOptions = [
        {
          'id': 1,
          'type': 'deposit',
          'icon': 'assets/wallet.svg',
          'title': 'Deposit',          
        },
        {
          'id': 2,
          'type': 'deposit',
          'icon': 'assets/wallet.svg',
          'title': 'Salary',        
        },
    ];

Comment: hi bro. how can i do this with two parameters?
like this:
[list1,list2].map((item1,item2)=>.....).tolist()

Comment: how to get index of title when using this function

Comment: The tab widget makes the difference from my previous approach

Answer (score 42):

I'm new to flutter. I found that one can also achieve it this way.

```
 tabs: [
    for (var title in movieTitles) Tab(text: title)
  ]
```

*Note: It requires dart sdk version to be >= 2.3.0, [see here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/whats-new-in-dart-2-3-1a7050e2408d)*

Comment: this one is better understandable.. thanks

Comment: It's the best way...

Answer (score 7):

I try this same method, but with a different list with more values in the function map. My problem was to forget a return statement. This is very important :)

```dart
 bottom: new TabBar(
      controller: _controller,
      isScrollable: true,
      tabs:
        moviesTitles.map((title) {return Tab(text: title)}).toList()
      ,
    ),
```

Comment: It's because your function is declared with ``{}`` the question is one line function

Comment: Simply change it to `map((title) => Tab(text: title)).toList()` , so no return needed...

Comment: Yes, this is the first (most voted) comment. I add this comment for code with more lines before return @Nima

Answer (score 7):

Yes, You can do it this way too

```
 List<String> listTab = new List();
 map.forEach((key, val) {
  listTab.add(val);
 });

 //your widget//
 bottom: new TabBar(
  controller: _controller,
  isScrollable: true,
  tabs: listTab
  ,
),
```

Answer (score 5):

```
tabs: [...data.map((title) => Text(title)).toList(), extra_widget],

tabs: data.map((title) => Text(title)).toList(),
```

It's working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

small addition to the AbdulMomen عبدالمؤمن [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49941395/5243472): for better performance you should set grawable false if list will not grow.

```
moviesTitles.map((title) => Tab(text: title)).toList(growable: false);
```