# How to display a saved list in Shared preferences in another list in another page(Favorite page)?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, flutter-listview, favorites

`Hello community, I'm new to the Flutter world and mobile app development and struggling with How to display a saved list in Shared preferences in another list in another page(Favorite page`

`The favorite button to save the list in` **Shared Preferences :**

```
        Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                      child: FlatButton(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.favorite,
                          color: Colors.green,
                          size: 25,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          SharedPreferences prefs =
                              await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

                          Article savedArticle = Article(
                              source: widget.list[i].source,
                              author: widget.list[i].author,
                              title: widget.list[i].title,
                              description: widget.list[i].description,
                              url: widget.list[i].url,
                              urlToImage: widget.list[i].urlToImage,
                              publishedAt: widget.list[i].publishedAt,
                              content: widget.list[i].content);

                          String json = jsonEncode(savedArticle);

                          //  print('saved... $json');
                          list.add(json);
                          prefs.setStringList('News', list);
                          print("shared..." +
                              prefs.getStringList('News').length.toString());
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
```

[This is a screenshot of the saved list in shared pref displayed in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0LF8.jpg):

[This is a screenshot of the list with the favorite button from where I saved the articles in the SharedPref by clicking the favorite button:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYcM1.jpg)

`My goal is to display the saved list in the shared preferences in another page (favorite articles page) in a list but without favorite button. Could any one help me PLEASE ? Thank you.`

Comment: Hey Dhouib, welcome to flutter and to asking questions on Stack Overflow. Could specify what exactly you are struggling with in your question? Is it pulling information from shared preferences, how to reuse your code to show the same UI, or something else?

Comment: @developerextraordinare thank you for your response.
I'm asking about how to get a list of Articles already saved in sharedPref with jsonEncode format from home page and display them in another list in another page (we could name it favorite Page). 
I've uploaded the example of the articles, it doesn't matter to display them with the same UI or not, I just need to display them in another list.
thank you.

Comment: I don't have time to write a good answer right now, but I would checkout resources for json serialization/ deserialization in flutter. Here are a few helpful resources: https://medium.com/flutter/some-options-for-deserializing-json-with-flutter-7481325a4450 (to and from json) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941361/dart-mapping-a-list-list-map (converting a list of strings to a list of something else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On another page you have to get shared preferences instance.

```
final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstange();
```

Then you can get your list by sharedPreferences.getStringList('News'); and convert to json by json.decoder;

If you want to make an instance of your Article class then you could implement a method inside of that that would return new instance of the class from json.
For example:

```
class Article {
  factory Article fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Article(id: json['id'], ...);
  }
}
```